# Deserialize JSON with "non-stable" values using kotlin serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I have not very well structured JSON from BE (that I cannot change) which was formerly handled with moshi (custom adapter for the issue). Now I am trying to use pure kotlin serialization instead, but as said, JSON structure doesn't help me much.

```
{
   "foo": {
       "version":1,
       "mask": [
          {
             "values": [
                  { "bar": 1, ... }
              ]
           },
           {
             "values": [
                  "important text i guess"
              ]
           },
       ]
    }
}
```

Now as you can see my issue is with **values** that can contains both *object* as well as *string*. All this should be parsed into kotlin where **values** looks like this:

```
data class Values(
  val bar: Int? = null,
  val text: String? = null,
  ...
)
```

Theoretically I can change local implementation, e.g. split the **values** class or something.
I've already tried to apply Polymorphic deserialization, but as I understand it was not able to recognise difference between two descendants of **values** without classDiscriminator set in JSON.

Any good advice?

**Update**

The polymorphic version I tried (in case I just made some error)

```
@Polymorphic
@Serializable
sealed class Values{
  
  @Serializable
  data class ObjectValues(
    val bar: Int? = null,
    ...
  )

  @Serializable
  data class TextValues(
    val text: String? = null
  )

}
```

and use it:

```
Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        serializersModule = SerializersModule {
            polymorphic(Values::class) {
                subclass(Values.ObjectValues::class, Values.ObjectValues.serializer())
                subclass(Values.TextValues::class, Values.TextValues.serializer())
            }
        }
```

error:

```
Polymorphic serializer was not found for missing class discriminator ('null')
JSON input: {"bar":42,...}
```

**Disclaimer**
I know that this would fix it all :)

```
"values": [ { "text":"important text i guess" } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `classDiscriminator` is not a mandatory requirement for polymorphic deserialization. You can use [content-based polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization) in this case.

All you need is to define a `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` for `Values` class with some logic for exact subclass serializer selection:

```kotlin
object ValuesSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Values>(Values::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = when {
        element.jsonObject["values"]!!.jsonArray.first() is JsonObject -> ObjectValues.serializer()
        else -> TextValues.serializer()
    }
}
```

and wire it as a serializer for `Values` class:

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = ValuesSerializer::class)
sealed class Values

@Serializable
data class TextValues(val values: List<String>) : Values()

@Serializable
data class ObjectValues(val values: List<Bar>) : Values()

@Serializable
data class Bar(val bar: Int)

@Serializable
data class MyJson(val foo: Foo)

@Serializable
data class Foo(val version: Int, val mask: List<Values>)
```

No need for `serializersModule`:

```
val result = Json.decodeFromString<MyJson>(json)
```

Comment: Thx a lot, this is correct answer while it responses to my question and pointed me to working solution. You saved my day!

At the end this is working solution (for slightly different json/kotlin objects)

part I:

```
object ValuesSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Values>(Values::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Values> {
        return when {
            element is JsonObject -> Values.ObjectValues.serializer()
            else -> Values.TextValues.serializer()
        }
    }
}

```

Comment: part II:

```object TextValuesSerializer: KSerializer<Values.TextValues>{
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
        get() = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("Text", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Values.TextValues {
        return Values.TextValues(text = decoder.decodeString())
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Values.TextValues) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.text ?: "")
    }
}